# Uncheck box but be able to recheck R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

In a shiny app I'm developing there is a check box I want to reset to off when I click an action button.  I've found code that unchecks the box when I click the button but then the button stays permanently unchecked and I'm not able to recheck it.  Does anyone have any idea how I can uncheck the box after pressing the button while maintaining the capability of checking the box?

Here are some attempts I've already tried that run into the issue discussed above:

```
ui <- fluidPage(

   # Application title
   titlePanel("Preflop Trainer"),

   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
         checkboxInput("checkbox",
                     "Check Box"),
        actionButton("reset",
                      "Reset the box")
      )
)

server <- function(input, output,session) {

     #I tried this
     if (input$reset) {
       if (input$reset != number) {
         updateCheckboxInput(session,"checkbox","Check Box",value = F)
       }
       number <- input$reset
     }

     #And I've tried this
     observeEvent(input$reset, {
       updateCheckboxInput(session,"checkbox","Check Box",value = F)
     }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try again. After correcting some bracket issues, this works for me:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

  # Application title
  titlePanel("Preflop Trainer"),

  sidebarLayout(mainPanel = 
      mainPanel(),
      sidebarPanel = 
      sidebarPanel(
        checkboxInput("checkbox",
                      "Check Box"),
        actionButton("reset",
                     "Reset the box")
      )

  )
)
server <- function(input, output,session) {


  #this works for me
  observeEvent(input$reset, {
    updateCheckboxInput(session, "checkbox", "Check Box", value = F)
  }
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you this code worked for me as well!  It looks like the issue I had was actually that I was putting the observeEvent code in my render plot code but it should have been outside of it.  It's not apparent in my original question because I stripped the code down to what I thought was causing the problem.  This is also why some of the syntax looked off originally.